# Android: Hiding soft keyboard when touching out of EditText

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-keypad

It is OS behaviour hiding softInputKeyboard when pressing Back button or Done button, I wanted to hide the keyboard when the user makes a click out of the EditText. So I created a BaseActivity and wrote the following code in it.

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handleReturn = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

        View view = getCurrentFocus();

        int x = (int) ev.getX();
        int y = (int) ev.getY();

        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            EditText innerView = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();

            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP &&
                    !getLocationOnScreen(innerView).contains(x, y)) {

                InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus()
                        .getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        return handleReturn;
    }

    protected Rect getLocationOnScreen(EditText mEditText) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        int[] location = new int[2];

        mEditText.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        rect.left = location[0];
        rect.top = location[1];
        rect.right = location[0] + mEditText.getWidth();
        rect.bottom = location[1] + mEditText.getHeight();

        return rect;
    }
}
```

Extended the above class for MyActivity and it works fine for EditTexts on its layout. But it is not working when I popup an AlertDialog with custom layout which has many EditText in it.

I touched out of EditText in the AlertDialog and even foreground of the Dialog but the keyboard is not getting dismissed.

How could it be hided on this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code. It works for me

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if ( v instanceof EditText) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                v.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I think you have not understood my issue stated above... keyboard should be hidden when I touch out of an AlertDialog which has custom layout

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to remember to achieve this -

suppose the xml struture is like

```
<ViewGroup focusable=true focusInTouchMode=true>
     <EditText />
</ViewGroup>
```

1. Make the parent viewgroup as **focusable=true & focusInTouchMode=true**
2. set `onfocuschangelistener()` on edittext, i.e.

   ```
   edittext.editCaption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
       }
   });
   ```